# How to solve this Element type is Invalid error in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, render

I am new to react , This same code is working in the tutorial. Please check this code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './SidebarOption.css';

function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div className="sidebarOption">
      <Icon />
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

This Error only shows up when I add the  Component

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Can you share the code for how you are passing Icon to this coponent?

Answer (score 0):

```
import './SidebarOption.css';

function SidebarOption( {text, Icon}) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebarOption">
          {Icon}
          <h2>{text}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

Comment: Icon is coming in as a prop

Comment: I have updated the answer. please have a look at it

Comment: Probably he is not passing it so the error is showing up

Comment: Thanks Erick , The Error got Solved.